# I can't center the button

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to make this button look good.

The form is supposed to be divided in 4 columns:

3 for the textfields and the last one should be the submit button.

Could you help me make it have the same height and padding as the text fields

**Link:** http://draidel.com.ar/tienda/promotoras/marina/

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
.wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-submit {
   height: 45px;
   margin-top: 24px;
   margin-left: 6px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try with this

```
.body .main_color input[type='submit'] {
    margin-top: 26px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

Also you can add a Media queries for responsive like

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .body .main_color input[type='submit'] {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    }
}
```